# How to sync one popup window is always above another popup window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to sync one popup window is always above another popup window ? Both windows are in the same process but in different threads.
Similar method the system uses for owner and owned windows, but such windows must belong same thread. In my case, there are two different UI threads in one process and windows are created in those different threads.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SetWindowPos(window_1, window_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: :) and periodically monitor window_2 state for update window_1 Z-order (after user switching to another process relative z-order can be changed by system) ?

Comment: @23W: Otherwise, you should create the top window as a modal child of the other window.

Comment: Agreed with @MM.'s last comment, except that you don't want a child (or modality). All you want is a simple pop-up window, owned by the other window. To get this, use the `WS_POPUP` style (instead of `WS_OVERLAPPED` or `WS_CHILD`) when you [create the pop-up window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx), and specify the other window as its owner (`hWndParent`).

Comment: @CodyGray: Using Qt, these days I forget the details of WinAPIs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Similar method the system uses for owner and owned windows, but such windows must belong same thread.

This statement is incorrect. You can indeed make the owner of a window be a window from a different process. And that is the correct way to do what you desire.